# Show Data from gspread in RecyclerView in Kivy

Tags: python, listview, android-recyclerview, kivy, gspread

I'm stuck with an issue here.

I am working on an application where I need to show data which is read from Google Sheets in a tabular form. As far as I've researched on the web, the `RecyclerView` seems the best.

I've managed to read the data from Google Sheets using `gspread`

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope=['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
cred=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("spreadsheetexample-c77e6184ed8e.json",scope)
client=gspread.authorize(cred)

rawdata=client.open('Python_Kivy_Class12English').sheet1
data=rawdata.get_all_records()
```

**Could you help be in showing this data in a scrollable tabular format ?**
**And I need to make them clickable as well to show its details**

*Ps: The google file contains 2 Columns*